# Swiftmailer in xampp localhost doesnot send e-mail (have done a lot of research)

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

So I have spent days on trying to send e-mails using swiftmailer by php and I am using localhost xampp server v3.2.1, which the PHP version is 5.4.31 and my swiftmailer is I believe v5.3

Here is the PHP file :

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com',465,'ssl')
->setUsername('username@gmail.com')
->setPassword('password');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
->setFrom(array('username@gmail.com'))
->setTo(array('recipient@gmail.com'))
->setBody('Hello World')
;

$result = $mailer->send($message);
if (!$mailer->send($message,$failures)) {
  echo "Failures:";
  print_r($failures);
} else {
  echo "sent";
}
```

The page just returned blank and there are no e-mail sent or received.Please tell if there is anything I should configure before getting this to work or am I missing an important line of code or something.

Thank you in advance.

I keep trying and once I got an input in my error log which is :

```
[15-Oct-2014 16:33:49 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at

535 5.7.8 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 fn2sm17247597pdb.75 - gsmtp

"' in C:\xampp\htdocs\1\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php:386
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\1\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(281): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_assertResponseCode('535-5.7.8 Usern...', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\1\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\EsmtpTransport.php(245): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('RSET\r\n', Array, Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\1\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\Esmtp\Auth\XOAuth2Authenticator.php(56): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->executeCommand('RSET\r\n', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\1\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftma in C:\xampp\htdocs\1\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php on line 386
```

Comment: Since none of the echoes is executed, I assume you get an error message in your log file. Please provide that error.

Comment: Im sorry I don't know where can I find the log file for the error message, new at Swiftmailer, could you please guide me with the dir path ?

Comment: Check your XAMPP configuration for your `php.ini` which contains a line `error_log = <path>`. You can find the error log there.

Comment: Ok, so I found it inside c:/xampp/php/logs/php_error_log, I opened it with notepad, tried to open the php file to send e-mail again, and there is no input inside the log, (tried with other working php file, there is a record added in the log). Refresh the e-mail php file and there is still no additional record in the log, so what have I done wrong please guide me.

Comment: Either your php file is not run at all or you have an error somewhere else in the file. Can you provide the entire file?

Comment: It is the whole php file. I keep trying and once somehow I got an input in my error log, which I edited at my question above..

Comment: As the error states, your login credentials are not correct. Check your login and password.

Comment: Turns out I think gmail has blocked the access and I had to disable the security setting for this to work.. But all my sent e-mails went to spam/junk folder, do you happen to know the trick to make it not go to junk/spam ?? thank you so much, I really appreciate your help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It finally managed to send e-mails, what I had to do is change the security setting in my gmail account and disabled the security protection and now it sends e-mail perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your transporter like this:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('ssl://smtp.gmail.com', 465);
```

You can also check for exceptions:

```
try {
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
} catch(Swift_TransportException $exception) {
    var_dump($exception);
}
```

Comment: nope, still doesn't send or receive e-mail, am I suppose to configure my gmail account setting or something for this to work ??

Answer (score 1):

"535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted." means that third parties are not allowed access to your account. You need to grant them access to 3rd parties by uppdating your google account at:

https://myaccount.google.com/

Under "login" find the phrase "allow less secure apps access" and change this to "ALLOW.